# getting a sample from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I want to get a sample from a dictionary which holds image data. `Code 1` shows a simple example:

**Code 1:**

```
import numpy as np

a = dict(data_key_1=np.random.random((512, 512, 3)), 
         data_key_2=np.random.random((512, 512, 3)), 
         data_key_3=np.random.random((512, 512, 3)), 
         data_key_4=np.random.random((512, 512, 3)),
         data_key_5=np.random.random((512, 512, 3)),
         data_key_6=np.random.random((512, 512, 3)),
         data_key_7=np.random.random((512, 512, 3)),
         data_key_8=np.random.random((512, 512, 3)),
         data_key_9=np.random.random((512, 512, 3)),
         data_key_10=np.random.random((512, 512, 3))
        )
sample_keys = ['data_key_2', 'data_key_1', 'data_key_7', 'data_key_4']
```

**Desired Output:**

The output should contain the images at the keys specified by the items in `sample_keys` list, stored in the `a` dictionary.

**What I've tried:**

I thought that it could be done as with `nympy`'s fancy indexing as shown in `Code 2`, but got an `Error 1`.

**Code 2:**

```
a[sample_keys]
```

**Error 1**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-317-bf897da15ff6> in <module>
----> 1 a[sample_keys]

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

**Naive solution:**

I realize i can do it with a for loop like in `Code 3`, but I'm interested in a more "elegant" (i.e. without loops, and as less lines of code as possible) solution.

**Code 3:**

```
X = []

for image_id in sample_keys:
    X.append(a[image_id])
```

I'd appreciate any help for getting the desired output. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want read the list values one by one

```
a = 'a'
b = 'b'
c = 'c'
data = dict(a=[12,45],b=[45,78,90],c=[11])

sample_keys = [a,c]
for key in sample_keys:
    print(data[key])
```

output

```
[12, 45]
[11]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't index a list with a dictionary.

```
for key in sample_keys:
    if key in a:
        a[key]  # Now do any operation with it
```

Happy coding.